# Chat requirement to post images should be made explicit

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, images

There is (apparently) a 100 reputation requirement to upload and post images through chat.

There isn't any easily located documentation on this, however. 100 global reputation is listed as the privilege for [creating chat rooms](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/chat-rooms), while the chat FAQ and help both do not mention any restrictions on uploading images.

As such, could somewhere other than [Tim Stone finding an ancient chat message from back when it was even higher](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/89?m=200705#200705) be used to indicate that there is a reputation requirement in chat for uploading images?

Comment: It could be listed in the [Create and Edit Chatrooms](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/privileges/chat-rooms) privilege, we already have 2 privilege items in the list for 100 but neither mentions uploading images to chat.

Comment: Is this 100 reputation including or excluding the association bonus? I have over 100 reputation (but under 200) and do not have the ability to upload images to chat.

Answer (score 13):

I added it to [the privilege wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms)

> #### What other new privileges in chat do I get?
>
> At 100 reputation you also get access to the "Upload image" button in
>   chat.