# Sending images in chat

Tags: support, chat, images

[image]I want to send screenshots and images in chat. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You click the upload button, I'm not sure if theres a rep limit though

Comment: Can you see an upload button in [this](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) chat room? Just to confirm its not a chat room specific issue

Comment: Related: [Chat requirement to post images should be made explicit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124078/chat-requirement-to-post-images-should-be-made-explicit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the "upload" button. You'll have to take the screenshots yourself (the PrntScrn button on most computers)

[image]

---

Looks like there's a rep requirement for using the "upload image" button, it seems to kick in at 100 rep. You can still *post* images though. Upload it using the "upload image" button on the main site and post a link in chat.

Comment: yeah, Some one told me to use Upload Button. But i my chat room i am not ale to ssee that button

Comment: @DineshKanivu Tried refreshing the page? Care to provide a screenshot of the page?

Comment: i have added the screensots

Comment: plz check i have shared Screenshot

Comment: @DineshKanivu Yeah, seems like there's a rep requirement.

Comment: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1525371#1525371

Answer (score 0):

If the image you want to send is online, then just send the link into chat. If it ends in a supported image type then it will be one-boxed. I know that `.gif`, `.jpg`, `.png` all work for example.

If not, a popular way to get the image online is to use [imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and upload it there then share the url.

Comment: i can share the URL, then also image is not coming but the URL

Comment: @DineshKanivu - It must only be the URL in the message, nothing else. Otherwise, that is more than likely a result of the URL not ending in an image format. Sometimes just to kick start the one-box you can append `.jpg` to the end of your URL just to see if it works.

Comment: Or better. Just go to any question -> click on answer box -> click Ctrl+G -> upload image -> share the link of the image given on the answer box.

Comment: @TravisJ - If we share the image link it will be automatically show in the chat. E.g. I added `http://i.stack.imgur.com/oaroq.png` which looks [like this](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1525371#1525371)

Comment: How can iadd image instead of link