# Rationale for having different rep requirements for uploading images to the chat and the main site

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, chat, images

To post an image in a question/answer an user requires at least 10 rep points (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129833/warn-new-users-earlier-that-they-cannot-post-links-or-images)).
To be able to upload an image in the chat, the rep requirements is instead 100 rep point (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124078/chat-requirement-to-post-images-should-be-made-explicit)).

Is there any reason to that? I am asking because *IF* the rationale is to provide more protection inside the chat, the protection is easily circumvented by uploading the image via the question editor, and then copying the link to the chat. Basically, the more restrictive requirement fail to reach its goal - assuming that blocking uploads from new users was indeed the target.

I am not proposing to change that (it doesn't seem worthy the effort) but I was curios to know if this is just a refuse caused by successive changes to the system or if there is actually a different rationale to this that I am missing.

[note: I will remove the double Discussion/Support tag as soon as I can focus if the question has a staff answer - support or will prompt a discussion]

Answer (score 7):

I don't know, and I actually can't understand why there would be a need for a difference in the required reputation for the upload in both places. Chat can be moderated, just like the site can, so there is no real need for the 100 reputation.

If it is spam or low quality, another user in chat could easily flag the post. Regular users can handle the flags too, so no real need for a moderator here.

I think this will justify a feature request to lower the threshold, but I actually don't care much about it.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, those were my conclusions too. I avoided opening a request because I feel there may be some motivation I may be missing behind this choice, and also because I don't think changing the requirements may be really worth the effort if the current situation is just to be considered a logical bug.

Comment: Indeed. Do you think it is harder to moderate chat than the site? That isn't the case in my opinion, but others could think different.

Comment: The only somehow related comment I have found is a claim that a single bad image posted on the chat will probably be seen by a lot more user than one in a question before it gets removed. Still strange. Anyway, I will leave this question for a few more days, if no other official answer will be posted I probably will accept this one.

Comment: It really depends how crowded the room is. It might be the other way around for some popular tags on SO.

Answer (score 2):

The ability to upload image easily in chat is just a bonus. As explained in the answer for [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297058/can-a-user-with-20-100-reputation-still-upload-a-picture-into-chat-possible-bu), users with less than 100 rep can easily upload the image to a new post then copy and paste the URL.

My assumption is that when the chat system was created, the developers thought what privileges to give based on reputation, to give higher rep users incentive to use chat. In addition to  the ability to create rooms and to create gallery rooms, they came with this idea, of easier way to put images.