# Can a user with 20-100 reputation still upload a picture into chat? [possible bug]

Tags: bug, chat, privileges, images, uploader

I've just realized that until 100 reputation you don't get the upload image option in chat:

[Link Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms)

> [image: showing the privilege]

So that just means that the <kbd>Upload Image</kbd> button isn't there until you have 100 rep.

What would happen if one uploaded through the ask question's area and just copy pasted the link (very easy process)?

- Would the Image load since it's an imgur link (are they supposed to have the privelage, or is just supposed to be more inconvenient for them?)

or

- Would it just show the link

  ---

This is all you'd need to do: (then paste in chat box and it should load image)

[image: copying imgur link]

__

I have not been able to test any of this out as I'm not a <100 rep user, but I'm very sure that it would work.

Comment: No bug here. Having the upload button is just a bonus for those with enough rep.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's already documented in [chat-faq](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#talk) that you can attach image with url:

> It's also possible to insert images in chat. **Simply paste the URL to the image on a line all by itself and press <kbd>enter</kbd> or click the send button.** If the image is on your computer, click the upload button to share the image through our partner imgur.com — the URL to the newly uploaded image will automatically be inserted into chat on your behalf.

Though <kbd>Upload...</kbd> button is not available until 100 reputation, I think it is only intended to stop obvious-uploading images from newbies. Otherwise forgot using Q/A writing area, you can *even manually upload image from your computer directly to http://imgur.com/* (i.e bypassing SE for uploading image) and then copy-paste url in chat.