# How do I upload images in chat rooms?

Tags: support, chat, images

I wanted to upload several images to chat rooms, but apparently, I cannot find a way of finding a button to upload images to a Stack Exchange chat room.

The only way I think I can post images is by using screenshot applications, in which turn a screenshot into a website link that anybody can look at if they have the link available.

How do I upload images to chat rooms without having to send a screenshot link?

Comment: Much related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269481/rationale-for-having-different-rep-requirements-for-uploading-images-to-the-chat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't upload images into chat unless you have 100 rep.

Source, see the last line from the [100 Rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms) privileges.

> At 100 reputation you also get access to the "Upload image" button in chat.

---

The way to get around it is to upload the image to SE regular image uploader and then copy paste that image link into chat (it'll get embedded/oneboxed). Follow steps from [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297058/358161).

Comment: There are some chat rooms which somehow allow you to upload without reputation, for now, your question is very useful to me until I reach 100 Reputation.

Comment: @Devealte you can upload images on any room inside chat.stackexchange.com domain since [your overall SE reputation is more than 100](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/379519/devealte). However, you can't do it on Stack Overflow chat domain or MSE chat domain since you have less than 100 on each. It's really confusing, but that's how SE chat works.

Answer (score 4):

..............................

[image: .]

[image: .]

Comment: I cannot find that option, why?

Comment: @Devealte where do you want to chat?

Comment: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta